# How to use smileys in our text?

Tags: iphone

I am creating a chat application wherein I want to use smileys in the chat text. I went through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659935/implement-emoticons-in-xcode) but was wondering if there is some other way to use smileys. Should this be done through code or is there some setting in iPhone where smileys can be shown on keyboard?

Comment: check this link may be this will help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659935/implement-emoticons-in-xcode you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is correct, if you want to use smileys, you'll need to implement them in code yourself or use some third party component.

Also, you'll need to figure out a format to transmit them over the network.